# Load banner in Joomla article

Tags: plugins, joomla, banner

Is there any plugin that can load banner "id x" from banner component?
Or is there any other way, but not with {loadmoduleid x}?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Asking for extension recommendations on Stackoverflow is off-topic.  [joomla.se] Stack Exchange does not have rigid stance.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know.
Thank you for the information